# trouble upgrading cabal-install

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I'm having trouble upgrading cabal to version 1.17.0. My current version of cabal is:

```
edechter@helmholtz cabal-install (master) $ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0.3 of the Cabal library
```

Here's my attempt:

```
edechter@helmholtz cabal-install (master) $ cabal install cabal-install-1.17.0
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
rejecting: cabal-install-1.16.0.2, 1.16.0.1, 1.16.0, 0.14.0, 0.10.2, 0.10.0,
0.8.2, 0.8.0, 0.6.4, 0.6.2, 0.6.0, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.0 (global
constraint requires ==1.17.0)
```

I followed the instructions here: http://www.haskell.org/cabal/FAQ.html#dependencies-conflict
But I don't see anything that conflicts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you find `cabal-install` version 1.17.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.16.0.2 [is the latest version currently available on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install). If you want to try a pre-release version, I suggest using [`cabal-dev`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev):

```
$ git clone git://github.com/haskell/cabal.git
$ cd cabal/cabal-install
$ cabal-dev add-source ../Cabal
$ cabal-dev install
```

The `cabal` executable will be installed under `cabal-dev/bin`.